# Count text fields from csv dataset in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, count

I'm working with d3.js in order to make a simple bar chart. I have made bar charts using `d3.csv` data. However, now I'm trying to use only one column from csvfile.

All items from this column are string values, specifically, they're cities. Some of them are unique, but others appears more than once.

Example:

```
city
Mor
Gdl
Mex
Bog
Mad
Rio
Bar
Mor
Gdl
Mor
Rio
Mor
Bog
Mor
```

I want to create a bar chart using this column. `x value` will be the City and `y value` will be the number of times the city appears.

I'm working with this code. However, I can not get `y value`:

```
d3.csv("../cities.csv", function(error, dataset) {
    dataset.forEach( function(d) {
        d.count = +d.city;
    });
    x.domain(dataset.map( function(d) { return d.city; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.count; })]);
    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis)
        .append('text')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .text('Número de contratistas');
    var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.city); })
        .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
        .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.count); })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return h - y(dataset.map(d.count));});
});
```

From this code, my first attempt to get the counting from each city was:

```
dataset.forEach( function(d) {
    d.count = +d.city;
});
```

How can I improve this fucntion in order to get this kind of bar chart?

Any suggestions to improve it are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you would like to count how often each city occurs and store it in d.count.
Try this:

```
// define count object that holds count for each city
var countObj = {};

// count how much each city occurs in list and store in countObj
dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    var city = d.value;
    if(countObj[city] === undefined) {
        countObj[city] = 0;
    } else {
        countObj[city] = countObj[city] + 1;
    }
});
// now store the count in each data member
dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    var city = d.value;
    d.count = countObj[city];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Stuurpiek I tried your example, but it doesn't plot the values from each city. I'm thinking if d3.histogram() could be a solution.

Comment: After a little change of my code, your example works great! Thanks!

Comment: One question: What does `undefined` represents?

Comment: @estebanpdl can you share your changed code that worked?